# How do I factor polynomials with power 3 and above?

Tags: polynomials

All of the videos I've found do things like "let's try -1. oh, it works! okay, now let's divide it out and find the next root".  Is there really no other strategy other than guess and check?  A couple of times I've come across these high power polynomials in contests and I just have no clue what to do with them.  I'm asking this question specifically now because there's a question in my textbook that asks me to find the two imaginary roots of a polynomial of 4th power.  Clearly guess and check is not going to work as well with imaginary numbers, and even with real ones it seems like a pain.  What strategies do you guys use to factor?

Comment: There are a variety of methods to find roots. You can use [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) to find what rational roots are possible for the cubic equation and check if each of the potential rational roots work. If your equation happens to be in the form $x^3-px+q$ you can use [Cardano's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula) to find roots. If all else fails you can use the (rather unwieldy) [General cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#General_cubic_formula).

Comment: By [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), if $r$ is a root of a polynomial then $x-r$ divides said polynomial. Given this you can now just divide your polynomial by $x-r$ and get $(x-r)P(x)$ where $P$ is a polynomial. You can use long polynomial division or the more efficient [Synthetic division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division) to divide your polynomial.

Comment: For quartic equations, it becomes substantially harder to find roots. The general formula can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots). By the [Abel-Ruffini Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) it is in general impossible to find roots of quintic or higher order equations, hence your best bet in those cases would be to use numerical solutions like [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to estimate roots. (You can still use the Rational Root Theorem to see if any rational roots exist).

Comment: If the roots are pure imaginary, eg $\pm ai$ then you simply have a factor $(x^2+a^2)$. If they're complex, then they must be conjugates, assuming the coefficients of the polynomial are all real.

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact a Cubic Formula, which can give you the roots, and make factoring trivial...although it is a little more complicated than the famed Quadratic Formula; see here https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/. And there is also a Quartic Formula, but that is much more complicated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Solving_a_quartic_equation . And in fact there is $\textbf{not}$ a general equation for 5th and higher order polynomials; a famous theorem known as Abel–Ruffini theorem.

But that is besides the point.

For factoring, particularly in contests; there is normally a trick to see, which is what makes the problems so rich. There are often various symmetries that can be used, or a quantity you can add and subtract which allows you to complete squares, polynomial division, etc.

If we are told roots are rational, then there is a lot that can be accomplished by guess and check, which is often what is taught in high school. However in the case where you have a Quartic Polynomial, I would assume the first step would be to split it into a product of two Quadratic Polynomials and go from there, since if there are 2 imaginary roots, they are probably conjugates of one another which can be expressed in one quadratic polynomial.

There is no general strategy of factoring, just various techniques.